# Get HTML body text only, no tags

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, email, uiwebview

I have no background or any knowledge of web development/designing and I'm currently working on an Email client application on iPhone, using UIWebView to read/write emails.

I download the email as an object and fetch the subject, date, addresses and body from this object, but the email body is an HTML string with tags.

**My goal:** To view the email body as a normal string without tags, like iPhone Mail app, or Gmail app.

*Here is good example:*

[image: GMAIL][image: MYMAIL]

Thanks!

Comment: Check this tutorial, it says how to parse html in ios: [RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSAttributedString` with `UITextView` or `Label` whatever you like

```
NSString *oldHTMLstring = @"<b>Testing</b>.<br><i>html</i>,<br><u>body text.</u>";
NSAttributedString *newHTMLstring = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[oldHTMLstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

[textView setAttributedText:newHTMLstring]; // sets attributed text
[textView setText:[newHTMLstring string]]; // sets normal text
```

This will automatically convert HTML to appropriate text

Comment: This looks like the best answer, but this is what im getting: Testing{
NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1"; NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x124d2a750> font-family: \"Times.    


Something to do with the Encoding? Or document attribute? Thanks!

Comment: I need your `html` for that.It should parse correctly.

Comment: <b>Testing</b>.<br><i>html</i>,<br><u>body text.</u>

Comment: Have you set in `textView.attributedText = string;` you do not need to check the string

Comment: It is working fine just set in `textView` as `textView.attributedText = string;`

Comment: @emotality I have checked here it is working fine with your `html`

Comment: I really want this to work and I really dont want to argue :( its showing attributedText in my tableview and its lagging terribly. I just want a normal string out of it. Even if I NSLog it gives the text attributes. From: "<b>Testing</b>.<br><i>html</i>,<br><u>body text.</u>" I just want to get "Testing. html, body text."

Comment: how you are setting.Are you setting in `label` or `textView`??

Comment: I fixed it, edited the answer. Tableview is laggy now but I will fix this, thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!